# Not understanding Reusing Table View Cells

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have made major changes and setup a custom class for the TableView Cell.

Cell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Cell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *month;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *date;
@end
```

Cell.m

```
#import "Cell.h"

@implementation Cell
@synthesize date, month;
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(1,1,69,69);

    float limgW =  self.imageView.image.size.width;
    if(limgW > 0) {
        UIFont *cellFont3 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialRoundedMTBold" size:9];
        UIFont *cellFont4 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialRoundedMTBold" size:18];
        self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(82,0,228,53);
        self.detailTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(82, 20, 228, 53);
        self.month = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 10, 53, 21)];
        self.month.font = cellFont3;
        self.month.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        self.month.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        self.date = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(11, 21, 50, 45)];
        self.date.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.date.font = cellFont4;
        self.date.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

    }
}
@end
```

Then in my TableView code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    Cell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[Cell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }


    RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM"];
    NSString *monthfromdate = [formatter stringFromDate:entry.articleDate];
    NSLog(@"%@", monthfromdate);
    [formatter release];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter2 setDateFormat:@"dd"];
    NSString *datefromdate = [formatter2 stringFromDate:entry.articleDate];
    NSLog(@"%@", datefromdate);
    [formatter2 release];

    if ([monthfromdate isEqualToString:@"01"]) {
        self.currentmonth = @"January";
    }
    if ([monthfromdate isEqualToString:@"02"]) {
        self.currentmonth = @"February";
    }
    if ([monthfromdate isEqualToString:@"03"]) {
        self.currentmonth = @"March";
    }
    if ([monthfromdate isEqualToString:@"04"]) {
        self.currentmonth = @"April";
    }
    if ([monthfromdate isEqualToString:@"05"]) {
        self.currentmonth = @"May";
    }
    if ([monthfromdate isEqualToString:@"06"]) {
        self.currentmonth = @"June";
    }
    if ([monthfromdate isEqualToString:@"07"]) {
        self.currentmonth = @"July";
    }
    if ([monthfromdate isEqualToString:@"08"]) {
        self.currentmonth = @"August";
    }
    if ([monthfromdate isEqualToString:@"09"]) {
        self.currentmonth = @"September";
    }
    if ([monthfromdate isEqualToString:@"10"]) {
        self.currentmonth = @"October";
    }
    if ([monthfromdate isEqualToString:@"11"]) {
        self.currentmonth = @"November";
    }
    if ([monthfromdate isEqualToString:@"12"]) {
        self.currentmonth = @"December";
    }


    NSString *currentday = datefromdate;


    NSString *articleDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:entry.articleDate];
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialRoundedMTBold" size:15];
    UIFont *cellFont2 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialRoundedMTBold" size:12];

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"calendar1.png"];
    cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;



    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", articleDateString, entry.blogTitle];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = cellFont2;

    cell.textLabel.text = entry.articleTitle;
    cell.textLabel.font = cellFont;
    cell.month.text = currentmonth;
    cell.date.text = currentday;
    return cell;
}
```

This solves  problems with repeats, or labels being written on top of each other, but only the cell.textLabel shows anything.  Nothing appears on the detailTextLabel or the other 2 labels I set up.

Comment: first thing I would do is to check your datasource. It may be that the error was in your parsing of the feed and the creation of the data model. In other words, look through the array of entries and make sure that it in fact does not have those repeating entries in it. If it does then your tablview code is correct and the problem may be in your parser.

Comment: @bennythemink The datasource is correct.

Comment: ok quick question then to clarify the problem, is the entry for October 14 the last entry in your datasource or are there three more entires in your datasource that are being hidden by/not displayed in, the 29th, 30th and 03 cells?

Comment: @bennythemink there are 3 more after 14th

Comment: @bennythemink If I move the code outside of the {} it will show all the entries, but when I scroll to the lower cells it shows all the label and detaillabel text from previous cells with new entries on top, yet for some reason the text on the calendar never gets written on top of again.

Comment: I wish I had an answer for you. Try setting the labels text property to be empty before assigning new text, that should clear them and stop the text on top of text issue. With your main issue I would start debugging by displaying some NSLogs of the datasource and label text assignments for the three last rows. Best of luck!

Comment: @bennythemink See the edits I just made.  Got the issue fixed with not loading everything, just can't get all the TextLabels to load now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is incorrect. When cells are being reused, it does not necessarily means that the cell on index path {0,1} will be reused the next time that this particular index path cell becomes visible. A cell of the same identifier will be used, and it might contain the data of a different cell at a different index path. Your approach should be to dequeue or initialize the cell depending on the cell existence after dequeing, but always assign data on the cell based on the index path .

A few words of advice: do not create/release NSDateFormatter objects inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. It will give you performance issues. Also, for organization purposes, please subclass UITableViewCell and create the interface properly. Adding them on the fly is messy and confusing.

Also, looking at what you are trying to do, you might want to take a look at NSDateFormatter's monthSymbols and weekdaySymbols method, and [NSDateComponent documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You can get the months and day information instead of having 12 "ifs" to get the months.

Comment: I clarified what the actual problem is, and added some images showing it.

Comment: See the edits I just made.  Got the issue fixed with not loading everything, just can't get all the TextLabels to load now

Answer (score 0):

moving this to an answer as I think it may be the solution (hopefully).

I think your labels are not displaying correctly because you have them in the layout subviews method. This method gets called automatically when you do something like making a call to setFrame, addSubview or resizing the view. You are not making any of those calls in your cellForRowAtIndexPath so the OS is not automatically making a layout subview call (I hope that makes sense and is correct). If I were you I would have a separate XIB for the table cell, its a lot easier to manage.